# How to import to an existing object using ES6 syntax

Tags: jquery-mobile, import, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how to get this statements using es6

```
var $ = require('jquery');
$.mobile = require('jquery-mobile');
```

I'm doing this but idk if this is the best way

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQMobile from 'jquery-mobile';
$.mobile = jQMobile;
```

any suggestions are welcome! :)

Comment: Looks fine. Are you trying to achieve something in particular? A single dependency for both jQuery & jQM?